# Quick link means I can't get the exact chain length I need

Tags: chain

RE:11 speed chain

Hi, probably being silly here, but my new quick link chain has two more links than my original. I've removed one but for the quick link to work/fit I'll have to remove two more, so am I better off one to long or one two short or am I totally missing something.

Comment: I do not understand your questiin. At all. A quicklink just replaces two plates and roller spindles from the original chain. There should be no change at all. A picture could help.

Comment: The quick link has to attach to an inner chain link (the quick link becomes the outside plate). If I remove one more section of chain (to match the original) I'll be left with an outside chain link (I could be talking about half chain links if a link includes the inner and outer section)

Comment: Practically speaking, a chain that is an inch too long is rarely an issue.

Answer (score 4):

A chain must consist of an equal number if inner links and outer links. You cannot connect an outer link to an outer link or an inner link to an inner link.

A normal master link or quicklink replaces one of the outer links and two pins. But you leave the corresponding inner link in place. Then you connect the two inner links on both ends of the chain by the quicklink. Therefore, no change in the chain length happens.

This is one of the many videos that show the procedure. You really just replace the outer link with the quicklink, but the chain remains the same:

The video thumbnail should illustrate the quicklink location on the finalized chain quite nicely (pointed to by the arrow).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I'll count the links in the old chain. Size difference may be a result of chain stretch

Comment: @Steveo If it's the case that your chain was stretched half a link over it's whole length, you'll likely need a cassette as well.